# HtmlUnit: click on anchor does not trigger any event

Tags: javascript, java, html, htmlunit

im trying to click on this link:

```
<a id="table_statementlist_get_ib_table:0:ordernumber" class="OraLink" href="#" onclick="return _chain('disable_load_window();','submitForm(\'ib_trn_base_pas_statementlist_get\',0,{source:\'table_statementlist_get_ib_table:0:ordernumber\'});return false;',this,event,true)" name="table_statementlist_get_ib_table:0:ordernumber"> 6 </a>
```

and save some file that is returned to the browser. I have added WebWindowListener with implemented webWindowContentChanged method to my WebClient, which looks like this:

```
@Override
public void webWindowContentChanged(WebWindowEvent webWindowEvent) {
    WebResponse response = webWindowEvent.getWebWindow().getEnclosedPage().getWebResponse();
```

I have found that anchor by xpath, but when i want to fire click() method on it, webWindowContentChanged is not triggered.
Other links works just fine. Timeout for javascript is decent i guess:

```
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(30000);
```

Any suggestions how to get that file? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
```

should be called after click().
I thought it was a property for the case some javascript would appear